# how to fix "ValueError: Can't write to ZIP archive while an open writing handle exists."

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl, zip, valueerror

I was trying to do is that create an Excel file and   save the Excel file
but when I try to save the it,give an error.

I have try openpyxl to save Excel file.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
print(type(wb))

wb.save('balances.xlsx')
```

---

```
C:\Main\python.exe "C:/Users/owly/OneDrive/Desktop/python project case1.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/owly/OneDrive/Desktop/python project case1.py", line 21, in <module>
    <class 'openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook'>
        wb.save('balances.xlsx')
      File "C:\Main\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 408, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
      File "C:\Main\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 293, in save_workbook
    writer.save()
      File "C:\Main\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 275, in save
    self.write_data()
      File "C:\Main\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 67, in write_data
        archive.writestr(ARC_APP, tostring(props.to_tree()))
      File "C:\Main\lib\zipfile.py", line 1773, in writestr
    "Can't write to ZIP archive while an open writing handle exists."
    ValueError: Can't write to ZIP archive while an open writing handle exists.
    Exception ignored in: <function ZipFile.__del__ at 0x0C6E85D0>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Main\lib\zipfile.py", line 1789, in __del__
    self.close()
      File "C:\Main\lib\zipfile.py", line 1798, in close
        raise ValueError("Can't close the ZIP file while there is "
    ValueError: Can't close the ZIP file while there is an open writing handle on it. Close the writing handle before closing the zip.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Do you have the file open in Excel at the same time?

Comment: no,I did not open Excel file.

Comment: I do not fully understand this Issue but maybe this bug-report is relevant here: https://bugs.python.org/issue36434 I can reproduce the problem with Python 3.7.3 (Debian 10 stable), too.